# Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, liferay

I want to create a liferay plugin portlet using liferay-maven-plugin in eclipse but every time I try to do that I got this error :

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'sample-portlet'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Comment: Have you installed new 6.2.1 maven plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure,
How can I do that? It appears in new project wizard but I don't know is that necessary to install it individually or not!

Comment: If you try to browse the repos you get a 404 error. It seems that the repos from which you are trying to fetch the maven dependencies are not maintained anymore.

Are you using old mirrors ? Can you please display your maven settings.xml file. It is located at:
 - `C:\Users\you\.m2\settings.xml` on windows
 - `~/.m2/settings.xml` on linux/unix/osx

Answer (score 5):

1. Close eclipse
2. Go to your home directory (e.g. `C:/users/your_user_name` on Windows)
3. Find and delete the `.m2/repository` folder
4. Make sure your connected to the internet
5. Start eclipse
6. keep the internet connected and let maven update all dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error using Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite [STS] actually) when I tried to create a Maven project

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved ...
```

Looks like maven did not like http (which I had at some point setup using .m2/setting.xml) and was refusing to download what it needed.

```
501 HTTPS Required. 
Use https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
More information at https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required
```

The above site told me the following:

```
Effective January 15, 2020, The Central Repository no longer supports insecure 
communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are 
encrypted over HTTPS.
```

So I changed the http to https

But I still needed to import the maven certificate into java truststore.  To do that I exported the repo.maven.apache.org certificate and import it using Java 'keytool' command.

Here I have listed one way I do the certificate import.

[Spring tool suite- SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764343/spring-tool-suite-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certificati/59569901#59569901)

As a last step I had to restart STS.  After that it seemed to work for me.

For me lesson here is to start using https from the start wherever it is needed so that I do not run into problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems maven is no longer supporting unsecured protocol so I changed the maven repository URL from http to https and it worked for me.

```
<mirror>
<id>nexus</id>
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
</mirror>
```

Check below link for more information
https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required