# Spring tool suite- SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am working on STS and while creating a new spring-boot project, it shows following error:

```
 SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

since it access https://start.spring.io as a service URL.

I am working in a corporate network and they have their own certificates and security rules. I looked into web but could not find any clear solution for STS. How should I add certification path in STS for  given URL.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try below steps it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569901/9301392 thanks @user2125853

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **http** instead of **https** in the URL
http://start.spring.io

The following error will be resolved
"**SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**"

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in Spring Tool Suite 3 Version: 3.9.9.RELEASE
The moment i add  http://start.spring.io it get changed to  https://start.spring.io automatically.

Comment: Seems like http gets redirected to https, so this may not work.  I have added an answer to list what I did to get it to work.

Comment: In STS version 4,if i change https to http, it's automatically redirecting to the https, any one please help me to resolve this

Comment: @SrikanthJanapati Were you able to find the solution? I'm facing the same issue with STS 4

Comment: @coderpc please try this https://programmersought.com/article/68482773221/

Comment: @coderpc - in my case i disconnected the VPN then it's working fine

Answer (score 24):

It would seem like the http now gets redirected to https.  So changing https to http may not work.  I am barely familiar with digital certificates. However, I have simply listed what I had to do to get it to work for me.  This is perhaps what @Strelok has suggested.

I am on Windows 10 and JDK 1.8.0_144 64bit.  I am also behind a corporate proxy.  I did the following to get it to work for me.  If you are in a similar situation it may work for you.

Export the corporate certificate (There may be other easier ways of doing this)

1. On Chrome, I went to https://start.spring.io
2. On the location bar clicked on the 'Lock' symbol next to https.
3. Selected 'Certificate(Valid)' on the ensuing pop-up.
4. On the resulting dialog box, clicked on the 'Certificate Path' tab, from under certificate path tree **selected the root node**, and then clicked on 'View Certificate'
5. On the resulting dialog box, clicked on the 'Details' tab and then clicked on 'Copy to File'
6. This brings up the 'Export wizard', clicked on 'Next'.
7. Left the certificate format to default 'DER encoded..', clicked on 'Next'.
8. Provided file name (.cer extension) for the certificate.
9. Clicked Finish.

The above steps exported a certificate to a file that I imported into truststore (cacerts).

To import

- Opened a 'Command' prompt as Administrator to import the certificate
- Went to bin directory of Java installation (this step is not needed if jre/bin is in your path)
- Ran the following:

  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin>keytool -importcert -alias your-alias -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file C:\certificate-file-location\saved-certificate-file.cer

(Substitute your java location, certificate file location and certificate file name as appropriate.  The 'storepass' should be 'changeit'.)

Restarted STS

Comment: Does storepass indicate the keystore password?

Answer (score 21):

I encountered the same problem and tried this: Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections Change mode to Manual

It works fine now.

Comment: It's a generic solution. This should be an accepted answer.

Comment: Faced the same issue before encountering this solution, Kudos, It works.

Answer (score 18):

The simplest solution is to install your corporate certificate into the `cacerts` keystore of the JDK.

```
<JAVA_HOME>/bin/keytool -import -alias CorpProxy -keystore <JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file your_corp_cert.crt
```

You will be prompted for the keystore password which is `changeit` by default.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead of the workarounds above.  Also, this will help with other issues such as installing plugins from marketplace.

Comment: you saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In the case if none of above work, try below steps. It works fine for me as I was also working under corporate network, had same issue.

1. Close STS tool if open.
2. Locate STS.ini file (mostly where you have installed STS tool and have STS.exe)
3. Edit STS.ini. Add following two line at the bottom (Use your JDK location, below one is just a sample)

   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts

   -Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
4. Save STS.ini and restart the STS.exe.

It works in my case. Thank you.

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: The `.ini` file will have the same filename as the `.exe` file. It was `SpringToolSuite4.ini` in my case

Answer (score 3):

In Corporate Network, you may not have admin rights to import to `cacerts` file. The below steps helps to use STS in corporate network without admin privileges

1. Know your %userprofile% directory

   - Start -> Run
   - type `%userprofile%` and hit enter
   - This opens a folder for which you may have write access. Note the path
2. Export the corporate proxy certificate

   - On Chrome, go to https://start.spring.io
   - On the location bar click on the 'Lock' symbol next to https.
   - Select 'Certificate(Valid)' on the ensuing pop-up.
   - On the resulting dialog box, click on the 'Certificate Path' tab, from under certificate path tree select the root node, and then click on 'View Certificate'
   - On the resulting dialog box, click on the 'Details' tab and then click on 'Copy to File'
   - This brings up the 'Export wizard', click on 'Next'.
   - Leave the certificate format to default 'DER encoded..', click on 'Next'.
   - Provide `CorpRootCA.cer` as file name for the certificate and save in `%userprofile%/cacerts` folder. You may have to create the `cacerts` folder in your `%userprofile%`
   - Click Finish
3. Identify the JRE Path used by STS

   - Open STS
   - Click Window -> Preferences
   - Click Java -> Installed JRE[image: Installed JRE Window]
   - Copy the location used by STS
4. Copy cacerts file

   - Goto the jre location from Installed JRE in explorer
   - Goto `lib/security` and copy the `cacerts` file
   - Goto `%userprofile%/cacerts` and paste it inside the director
5. Adding corporate proxy certificate using keytool

   - Goto the jre location from Installed JRE in explorer
   - Type `cmd` in the url bar to open command prompt at the location
   - `./bin/keytool -import -alias CorpProxy -keystore %userprofile%/cacerts/cacerts -file %userprofile%/cacerts/CorpRootCA.cer -storepass changeit`

   The 'storepass' should be 'changeit' which is the default password. If changed use the correct storepass
6. Making STS point to new certstore

   - Open the folder which contains the SpringToolSuite executable
   - There will be a configuration file with same file as executable. In my case it was `SpringToolSuite4.ini`. Open the file
   - Append the below lines after changing the `%userprofile`to match the user's directory. Update `trustStorePassword` as required. `changeit` is the default value

> ```
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%userprofile%\cacerts\cacerts
> -Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
> ```

7. Restart STS and it should no longer throw

> SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1):

Adding below to eclipse.ini

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts
-Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS users:

```
# step 1
# execute the command to get the certificates
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect start.spring.io:443

# copy the all certificates, stating in: Certificate chain (including this line)
# Ending in the last: -----END CERTIFICATE-----

# step 2
# create the cert file with this content
mkdir $HOME/certs
touch $HOME/certs/root.crt
vim $HOME/certs/root.crt
# paste the cert content

# step 3
# import the cert
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -importcert -alias your-alias -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file $HOME/certs/root.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by looking at error log view from eclipse and it was trying to download from GitHub website. Added certificate of GitHub URL using keystore and it worked.

```
keytool -import -alias cert4 -keystore "C:\Users\A\Downloads\jdk-17.0.6+10\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file "C:\Users\A\Downloads\Zscaler Root CA.crt"

keytool -import -alias cert5 -keystore "C:\Users\A\Downloads\jdk-17.0.6+10\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file "C:\Users\A\Downloads\Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net).crt"

keytool -import -alias cert6 -keystore "C:\Users\A\Downloads\jdk-17.0.6+10\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file "C:\Users\A\Downloads\Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t)_.crt"

keytool -import -alias cert7 -keystore "C:\Users\A\Downloads\jdk-17.0.6+10\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file "C:\Users\A\Downloads\github.com"
```

Note: As others suggested, add spring certificates too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue following two steps.

1. Firstly I imported certificate present on https://start.spring.io into the jdk cacerts.
2. Atlast I added the path of TrustStore and trustStore password in SpringToolSuite4.ini file.

   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\security\cacerts

   -Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by importing the SSL certificate into the CACERTS file.

However it should be noted, that Eclipse/ STS by default uses its own JRE (in its plugins folder) such as
::

(STS--RELEASE)\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\lib\security\cacerts

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I truned off my ZScalar's Internet Security. So check if you are behind any security firewall

[image]