# Unable to install plugins in Spring tool suite due to certificate issue

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am getting this error while trying the install the Sonar lint plugin.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This is same as : [Spring tool suite- SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764343/spring-tool-suite-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certificati)

So I tried this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964015/1711670 however it did not work for me.

As per my understanding the error basically means that eclipse is trying to connect with the market place server however it doesnt trust it. Is that right?

How do I fix this issue?

**Version details:** 
Java version 1.8.0_191

STS version
Version: 4.4.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201909171436

Comment: Does [running Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) with an [up-to-date and fresh JVM](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) work?

Comment: No it doesn't work. Do you know which certificates has to be imported for it work?

Comment: what extension are you trying to install from the Eclipse Marketplace? That should point you towards the certificate that is missing from your keystore.

Comment: I am trying to install sonarlint. The spring sts initializr project 
also doesn't work.