# Migration from Nexus to azure artifacts

Tags: azure, nexus, azure-artifacts

I have to migrate thousands of packages from Nexus to azure artifacts. There is no proper information anywhere on this including Microsoft documentation. can you please help with approach? I have maven ,nuget and other custom packages. I understand there are limitations on azure side and would like to understand how the migration would work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to migrate Nexus packages to Azure artifact refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops) and this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946185/how-to-migrate-maven-packages-from-nexus-to-azure-artifacts).

[image]

I referred above MS document and used the sample Java project > Edited my `pom.xml` like below:-

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myFirstApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myFirstApp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sid24desai0738</id>
      <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/_packaging/sid24desai0738/maven/v1</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Edit `settings.xml` by adding the PAT token with

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>sid24desai0738</id>
      <username>sid24desai0738</username>
      <password>grb5rmhexnkvaa4tewjr6birosck3hr4cpnbfez4i5y5uwaj42wq</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

</settings>
```

**Ran the commands below:-**

```xml
mvn build
mvn install 
mvn deploy OR
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=xxxxxx38::default::https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxx738/_packaging/sid24desai0738/maven/v1
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how to do it for multiple repos ? I think this is just for one repo right?

Comment: <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repo1</id>
    <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/_packaging/repo1/maven/v1</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>repo2</id>
 <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/_packaging/repo2/maven/v1</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>

Comment: </repository>
  <!-- Add more repositories if needed -->
</repositories>

Comment: I have thousdands of packages across different repos . will all go into a single project in azure devops?

Comment: If all your repos are in same project the packages can go in different feeds, By connecting to different feeds for separate packager per repos. You can also select organization level feed which will store the artifact in organization level and not project level:- https://i.imgur.com/58yjglQ.png