# Proxy Setting Issue with Maven update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, proxy

I am trying to do a maven update but I am got this messages

Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.0.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

And I am setting my proxy in user settings.xml like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer and it really helped me but instead using the cert from spring.io use the cert from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Answer link -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71770947/14733631

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).